# Как поймать значение через массив POST?

Tags: php

Как мне поймать значение на следующей странице через массив POST, если я, его имя не знаю? То есть на 1 странице, есть

```
$request = запрос

<input type="text" name="<?=$request['id']?>"/>
```

Пользователь вводит определенно значение, нажимает submit, и отправляет на следующую страницу. Но я же не знаю, какое у будет имя у `$_POST['неведомэ']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $inputName => $inputValue) {
      echo 'Для поля с именем '. $inputName .' введено значение - '. $inputValue;
      // соответственно дальше можешь работать со значениями
      // $inputName и $inputValue для построения запросов в БД, валидации
      // или чего-либо другого
}
```